# Change class, private or public string

Tags: php, class, private, public

There is a php class in which I like to change the variable, but I can't make it happen.
The Class:

```
class ShopCart 
{
    private $maincurrency = 'USD';

    private function set_Currency() {
        $maincurrency = 'GBP';
        return $maincurrency;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. Even if I make it public. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `$this->maincurrency` in the body of your method. Your current code creates and sets local variable, not a member.

Comment: Agreed, `$maincurrency` is a class variable. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need `$this`:

```
class ShopCart {
   private $maincurrency = 'USD';

   private function set_Currency() {
       $this->$maincurrency = 'GBP';
       return $this->$maincurrency;
   }
}
```

Otherwise you're creating a new variable local to the function and just using that.

[The manual does actually tell you this already](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Within class methods the properties, constants, and methods may be
>   accessed by using the form `$this->property` (where `property` is the name
>   of the property) unless the access is to a static property within the
>   context of a static class method, in which case it is accessed using
>   the form `self::$property`.

The documentation is your friend; *consult it before asking here please*.

---

<sup>You may also want to consider *not* `return`ing anything from a setter, though that's up to you. There are advantages to doing so, even if it's not all that conventional in PHP.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
class ShopCart {
    private $maincurrency = 'USD';

    private function setCurrency() {
        $this->maincurrency = 'GBP';
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not `return` because set logic suppose that you just set some variable value, not output or return it

Comment: On the contrary, this approach allows chaining. It's also what `=` does in most (all?) C-style languages.

Comment: and watch on method name that I've changed, you should use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) only, but do not mix.

Answer (score 0):

change `$maincurrency = 'GBP';` to `$this->maincurrency = 'GBP';`,
and also `return $this->maincurrency;`